# Que el usuario pueda modificar el tamaño de una columna de datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Es posible que se puedan ir modificando los tamaños de las celdas de un datatable de jquery como lo hace la herramienta excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para cambiar el tamaño de las columnas podrías hacerlo a través de la funcion **resizable** de **jquery ui**, el siguiente ejemplo es muy básico pero te puede servir:

```js
$('table th a').resizable({handles:'e'});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fiddle.jshell.net/css/result-light.css"> 
<style type="text/css">
  table th a { display: block; }
  td, th { border: solid; }
</style>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th><a href="#">Col 1</a></th>
        <th><a href="#">Col 2</a></th>
        <th><a href="#">Col 3</a></th>
        <th><a href="#">Col 3</a></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Dato 1</td>
        <td>Dato 2</td>
        <td>Dato 3</td>
        <td>Dato 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: está muy bueno, pero solo puedo hacer un resize desde el encabezado? puedo tomar la linea desde cualquier fila?

Comment: Si es posible, sin embargo te recomiendo alguna librería para no hacerlo desde cero, por ejemplo podrías utilizar la siguiente libreria para jquery: http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/